# Cannot add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install systemback 1.0 on ubuntu 14.04. But I get

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:nemh/systemba'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct
```

Please I need help.

Comment: what command you used to add PPA ?

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nemh/systemback

Comment: please follow my answer , and let me know the result =)

Answer (score 0):

Add the PPA to the software sources:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
```

... and you will see something like this:

```
 Simple system backup and restore application with extra features

Systemback makes it easy to create backups of the system and the users configuration files. In case of problems you can easily restore the previous state of the system. There are extra features like system copying, system installation and Live system creation.

This PPA contain the stable version of Systemback.

Currently supported Ubuntu releases:
- 14.04.X LTS
- 15.04
- 15.10
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpiv2ysmqh/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpiv2ysmqh/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 73C62A1B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpiv2ysmqh/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 73C62A1B: public key "Launchpad PPA for Kendek" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Comment: But I keep on getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The @A.B answer should work fine but in case you still are getting the same error -

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and add the PPA ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
```

<sub>reference [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html)</sub>